# REACT: Call an external js function in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Anyone know in reactjs how to be able to call that 'openSideMenu' function which is in the vanilla js file that I imported on the top?

[image: code]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: See [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: Pease read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of your code, it's not very accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The function will be scoped to the module and inaccessible outside it.

Rewrite the module you are importing so it exports the data you need.

---

A dirty hack would be to:

- Load the JS file using a `<script>` element
- Ensure that it sets the function as a global
- Access `window.thatfunction` inside the React app

but that's fiddley and has the usual problems of globals.

Answer (score 1):

To further what Quentin said, you're not doing react in a react-y way. To be clear, it's always going to be harder and more confusing to do stuff the wrong way when dealing with react.

The react way to do what you want is something like this:

```
function NavBarLogo({onLogoClick}) {
  return (
    <nav>
     <img ... onClick={onLogoClick}/>
     <img ... />
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Whatever renders `NavBarLogo` looks something like this:

```
function NavBarContainer() {
  cons [className,setClassName] = React.useState('closed');
  const handleLogoClick = () => setClassName(c => c === 'closed' ? 'opened' : 'closed')

 return (
    <div className={className}>
      <NavBarLogo onLogoClick={handleLogoClick}>
      ... other stuff
    </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you exported your **openSideMenu** function in your *sideMenuFunction.js* file as default, then you need to import like this:

```
import openSideMenu from '../../utils/sideMenuFunction';
```

if not as default, then you need to import like this:

```
import { openSideMenu } from '../../utils/sideMenuFunction';
```

Make sure the names are the same both where you import and from where you import and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call an external function, you have to export it from the file it's contained in.

So in your example, you would want to have:

```
import { openSideMenu } from '../../utils/functions.js';
```

and then in 'functions.js' you would have:

```
export const openSideMenu = () => {
  // Do Stuff Here...
}
```

And then you'll have no problem calling 'openSideMenu' from your onClick just how you have it